# Selenium and Node js - sites for learning more?

Tags: mobile-automation

Are there any websites you could recommend for learning Node Js with Selenium. I have some knowledge about Selenium. But I have not used Node Js with it.

Answer (score -1):

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-reliable-browser-tests-using-selenium-and-node-js-c3fdafdca2a9 is helpful for a high level view

A step by step gettig started guide is at https://team.goodeggs.com/getting-started-with-selenium-webdriver-for-node-js-f262a00c52e1

Another step by step guide is at https://simpleprogrammer.com/selenium-with-node-js/

npm guide https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to check any other websites for in depth learning of Node Js or this should suffice

Comment: That is an unanswerable question as it depends on your knowledge and background.  Some folks need 2 books, some need 10.